# How to read a variable content in Xcode console?

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, xcode, cordova

I'm using Xcode to program an ionic/angularJS app and I'm turning crazy with Xcode's console... I can't figure out how to see what's inside my `userData` variable after trying to use a facebook login cordova plugin (should be public profile and birthday infos, but I don't know how they are stored into `userData`).

As you can see, if the data is a simple `string` or `numeric` it is shown in the console logs, but as soon as the variable is an array, impossible. I know in Swift it's something to do, but how can I achieve this, to see what's inside `userData`, using angular and Xcode ?

```js
// THIS FUNCTION IS CALLED TO LOGIN WITH FACEBOOK 

function loginFunction()
{

var fbLoginSuccess = function (userData) {
  console.log("UserInfo: " + userData);

/* log : 

UserInfo: [object Object] 

*/

  facebookConnectPlugin.getAccessToken(function(token) {
    console.log("Token: " + token);
    
    /* log :
    
Token: *******q************xqxpoaxapzoxét0g3zefzefZCXtvlsEj7T1boIaO0YtT1QNNj7YUfXjdTZAfafktNbD34f**********5EOucsdcsceydiZD*
    */
  });
}

facebookConnectPlugin.login(["public_profile", "user_birthday"], fbLoginSuccess,
  function (error) {
    console.error(error)
  }
);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stringify your variable:

```
console.log("UserInfo: " + JSON.stringify(userData));
```

BTW you may find it easier to debug using Safari Web Inspector than Xcode's native console: https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/docs/using-web-inspector-remote-to-debug-ios-cordova-apps